# Understanding cdi Instance<> and .get() vs @Inject

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, cdi, jboss-weld

I'm a little confused about which to use in the following situation:

Suppose the servlet creates an Application that handles the user's http session, and the application is this:

```
public class Application extends AbstractHTTPApplication {

@Inject
private Instance<MainView> mainView;

public void setupApplication() {
   this.setView( mainView.get() );
}
```

Later on I have a `@SessionScoped` bean `SSB` that I want to inject into each user's bean:

```
@SessionScoped
public class SSB {}
```

Now, when I tried a regular `@Inject SSB ssb;` as a field in `MainView`, I do not get a new `SSB` for each user:

```
public class MainView {

@Inject
private SSB usersSSB;

   public someMethod() {
       usersSSB.doSomething();
       System.identityHashCode( usersSSB );
   }
}
```

Testing with two users, I get the *same* instance of `usersSSB` in both user's sessions.  I didn't think this was possible... I thought, since SSB is SessionScoped, a new one will be given to each user session, and no matter where it is `@Inject`ed it will refer to *that* user's `SSB`.

Instead, I tried:

```
public class MainView {

@Inject
private Instance<SSB> usersSSB;

   public someMethod() {
       usersSSB.get().doSomething();
       System.identityHashCode( usersSSB.get() );
   }
}
```

Now it reports a different `usersSSB` for each user, finally.

What's happening here? When I call `usersSSB.get()` later on in each user's session, will the `usersSSB.get()` return *that same bean* for *that same* user each time?

I'm running on Glassfish 3.1.2.

**Some More Info**

The Application class is being injected into the Servlet on a new HttpServletRequest:

```
public abstract class AbstractCdiApplicationServlet extends
    AbstractApplicationServlet {
@Inject
protected Instance<ApplicationWrapper> wrapper;

@Override
protected Application getNewApplication(HttpServletRequest request)
        throws ServletException {
    return wrapper.get().getApplication();
}
...etc etc
```

And the `ApplicationWrapper` is a `SessionScoped` bean:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@SessionScoped
public class ApplicationWrapper implements Serializable {
@Inject
private AbstractCdiApplication application;

public AbstractCdiApplication getApplication() {
    return application;
}
 }
```

Doesn't this mean that calling `@Inject SSB usersSSB` anywhere in MainView (or *any* object within that user's session) should give me that user's session-scoped bean, and always *that same* session-scoped bean, for each user's session? Meaning -- different usersSSB for different users, because each user has a different session.

After all, the `Application` itself is a `SessionScoped` bean, injected into and attached to the user's HTTP Session by the `getNewApplication` method of the servlet?  I mean, it is the Application object that injects and attaches the MainView class, after all, right? So that means MainView is a session-scoped bean, doesn't it?

I'm just trying to figure out how this all works, I guess. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thats very odd. Do you have this sample available for testing?

Comment: To be honest, I don't have a solid enough handle on this to make a simple test case... Is there a working maven archetype that will start you off with an http servlet creating an application for each new session? I could use that to build a test project and post it.

Answer (score 7):

This happen because '@Inject Instance<>' is dynamic obtained unlike to '@Inject'

If you do '@Inject' into ApplicationScoped bean then injection is obtained only once so in ApplicationScoped bean will be this same reference for all users

If you call .get() on '@Inject Instance<>' then reference to SSB is obtained dynamically each time when you call .get()

More about injection you can read here: http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.1.0.Final/en-US/html/injection.html

Comment: I've added some more info spurred by your comment, Krzusztof. Shouldn't `@Inject` into a SessionScoped bean (MainView) give the same object to that user, always? And should that `@Inject` give a *different* object to a different user, since they are in a different session?

Comment: What you actually get is a proxy which will do the lookup for the correct resource each time.